# JavaScript - Destroy existing AnyChart when running on change function

Tags: javascript, anychart

I have some visuals that display data based on the value of a drop down. When re-charting with new data when a new drop down value is selected, the chart object appears to get appended, or something other than overwritten. I’ve tried to clear the HTML element as part of the `onchange` function, but it hasn’t worked.

I was able to recreate the issue in [JSBIN](https://jsbin.com/danuxolaze/1/edit?html,js,output). I think the HTML element clearing doesn’t remove the chart stage. I would like the chart to appear as it does in the first `makechart()` function when the `onchange` is called. Can [this](https://github.com/AnyChart/AnyChart-Android/issues/108) solution be implemented within the `onchange` function?

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question after some more attempts. As part of the `makechart()` function, I added in to reset the element text. Before creating the chart, either for the first time or on data changes I added `document.getElementById(‘chartID’).textContent = ‘’;`

This caused the chart to be removed and then recreated.